# Thomae's function restriction

Tags: real-analysis

Define the function $h:[1,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as follows, $h(x)=0$ if the point $x$ in $[1,2]$ is irrational $h(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ if the point is rational, $x=\frac{m}{n},m,n \in\mathbb{N}$ and $\text{GCD}(m,n)=1$.

Prove that if $\epsilon>0$ then the set $T=\{x \in[1,2]:h(x)>\epsilon\}$ has only a finite number of elements.

I am having trouble with this proof I have seen the following:

for this function defined on $\mathbb{R},x\in\mathbb{R}$,$ T\cap [x-1,x+1]$ is finite for rational numbers in this intersection with denominators $n$ such that $|n|\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}$.The proof I am looking at states this is so, because of the restriction on the size of $n$. I am having trouble demonstrating that the set is finite how should I proceed in trying to show this? I would try to show more of an effective attempt on this, but I am struggling to know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us start by defining $k = \lceil 1 / \varepsilon \rceil$ so that $h(x) > \varepsilon$ holds precisely when $x$ can be expessed as a fraction with denominator $n < k$.
As we have $x \in [1, 2]$ that means that $x$ can be written as $\ell / n$ with $n \leq \ell \leq 2n$ giving us that $T = \{\ell / n \mid n < k \text{ and } n \leq \ell \leq 2n\}$ which gives us only finitely many possibilities since the ranges for choosing the denominator as well as the nominator are finite.